# Is it possible that in a Coolidge tube characteristic $L_α$ X-rays are emitted but not $K_α$ X-rays?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation, x-rays

> Is it possible that in a Coolidge tube characteristic $L_α$ X-rays are emitted but not $K_α$ X-rays?

Suppose the electron accelerated in the Coolidge tube knocks out the electron from the L shell then an electron from the M shell makes a transition to the L shell. In this case $L_α$ X-rays are emitted but not $K_α$ X-rays. The solution to the question says that it is not possible to have $L_α$ X-rays emitted without the emission of $K_α$ X-rays. Can someone tell me where I am wrong in my reasoning?